# How do I translate this ffmpeg command into fluent-ffmpeg for react-native?

Tags: ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

```
 ffmpeg.ffprobe(filePath, (error, metadata) => {
          const duration = metadata.format.duration;
          console.log(duration);
```

Up to here it's working, but then I need to use the following commands and don't know how to.
As far as I know, they should also be part of this callback.

```
ffmpeg -i filePath -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=start=timeStamp1:duration=5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[0v]; [0:a]atrim=start=timeStamp1:duration=5,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[0a]; [0:v]trim=start=timeStamp2:duration=5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[1v]; [0:a]atrim=start=timeStamp2:duration=5,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[1a]; [0:v]trim=start=timeStamp3:duration=5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[2v]; [0:a]atrim=start=timeStamp3:duration=5,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[2a]; [0v][0a][1v][1a][2v][2a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[cv][a]; [cv]scale=320:-2[v] " -map [v] -map [a] -y outputVideo.mp4
```